# How do I make double tap shortcuts?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, customization

I want to change the view angle shortcuts like Numpad1+Ctrl to double tap Numpad1, similar to pressing G twice to do something different than just pressing G once.

Is it possible to do this? I read something about modal maps but didn't understand if or how it was applicable to my case. Also, I rather not have to mess with coding just for this, but am willing to try if it is simple enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in Edit > Preferences > Keymap

Scroll at the bottom of the category 3D View > 3D View (Global) and click the <kbd>Add New</kbd> button.

Set the Identifier to `view3d.view_axis`. Set the corresponding view (here I used `Back`) and set the corresponding key (without double-tapping).

Then, change the Press method to "Double Click". Once might think it works only for mouse inputs because it says "click", but it works with the keyboard too.

[image: new shortcut]